# How to determine device type from `instruments -s devices`

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode7, tvos

By running `instruments -s devices`, you get a list of connected devices as well as virtual simulator devices:

```
Known Devices:
your.mac [uuid]
Physical Device 1 (9.1) [uuid] <--- unknown device type
Physical Device 2 (9.0) [uuid] <--- unknown device type
Apple TV 1080p (9.0) [uuid]
Apple Watch - 38mm (2.0) [uuid]
Apple Watch - 38mm (2.0) [uuid]
Apple Watch - 42mm (2.0) [uuid]
Apple Watch - 42mm (2.0) [uuid]
iPad 2 (9.1) [uuid]
iPad Air (9.1) [uuid]
iPad Air 2 (9.1) [uuid]
iPad Pro (9.1) [uuid]
iPad Retina (9.1) [uuid]
iPhone 4s (9.1) [uuid]
iPhone 5 (9.1) [uuid]
iPhone 5s (9.1) [uuid]
iPhone 6 (9.1) [uuid]
iPhone 6 Plus (9.1) [uuid]
iPhone 6s (9.1) [uuid]
iPhone 6s (9.1) + Apple Watch - 38mm (2.0) [uuid]
iPhone 6s Plus (9.1) [uuid]
iPhone 6s Plus (9.1) + Apple Watch - 42mm (2.0) [uuid]
```

The problem is that I can't tell what kind of device is listed on the physical devices. The only thing you really get is the OS version, but there's no way to use this since iOS and tvOS versions are so similar.

Is there any way to lookup a device type based off of a UUID? Or another way to list devices + device types?

Note: Using `xcrun simctl` doesn't do me any good since I don't care about the simulator, just the physical devices that are connected.